# Can't figure out jQuery JCombo

Tags: php, jquery

I am new in jquery. I was trying to use Jcombo plugin but that one wasn't working for me. Here what I did :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.prodiven.com/jcombo/jquery.jCombo.min.js"></script>   

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    /* simple combos */
    $("#state1").jCombo("getStates.php");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="state1"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

getStates.php file output was like this:

```
 {"1":"Bangladesh","2":"Arabic"}
```

Any idea why I can't see drop down selection. Thanks

Comment: Did  you check console? I think you need to add jQuery library before jCombo library.

Comment: Thanks just changed the code & added jquery first but still same problem. From console got this error "[19:16:37.741] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost/drop1/drop.php" and "[19:16:37.729] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://localhost/drop1/drop.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .. It was problem with the plugin. I just noticed that in jCombo.min.js script dataType was "jsonp" I changed it to :

```
dataType:"json"
```

now it's working...

Comment: nice, but scripts order was wrong too. Update it in your reply and make it as solutioned